# ViewAction button does not show up in gmail

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

ViewAction button does not show up in gmail

I have followed all instructions and I think I it should show up

- I have tested with email schema validation tool
- I am using same address from, to
- I am sending via smtp.gmail.com
- There is no DKIM / SPF but I can't set this up for @gmail.com email, right?
- I tested via [Apps Script Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial) and it worked, but need to get it work with my app too

Below is email source

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aside from making sure that you've copied the codes, make sure that you're also using the correct file names. The Apps Script Quickstart is working fine. This is the usual error everyone is making. Make sure you've read the guide properly. Don't skip details.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "using the correct file names"?

Comment: I followed the guide very properly, talking about this one https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/testing-your-schema

Comment: @LubošRemplík same problem, is there a solution?